# Podspec Linting issue for iOS10

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec, swift2

The framework developed has iOS10 dependancies, for example `Messages`. The podspec includes the line:

`s.ios.deployment_target = '10.0'`

But upon linting the following Error is listed:

`ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Simulator for iOS 10.0 is not available.`

Is there anything, currently, that can be done to get around this?

**Cocoa Pod Version - 1.1.0.beta.2**

Answer (score 3):

You should choose the Xcode8 version, by using:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Path_to_xcode8/Xcode.app/
```

Otherwise, Cocoapods will use Xcode7 to make sure that your pod is building, and since Xcode7 doesn't contain ios10, it doesn't build.

Comment: After this delete your derived data, then try lint command again.